# Angular CLI failes to serve or init, only message is "Error"

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

### Environment

```
$ ng --version
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.16
node: 6.7.0
os: win32 x64

$ npm --version
3.10.3
```

### Issue

Yesterday everything was working relatively well. I updated angular-cli using [these instructions](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli) and everything seemed to work. Today I try and start angular-cli and get a woefully uninformative error message:

```
$ ng serve
Error
```

I've tried reinstalling node and angular-cli again, but the issue remains.

### Questions

1. Is there a more verbose log I can inspect for either npm or angular-cli?
2. Should I use Node 4.6.0 LTS? I switched to v6.x.x when I first started using angular-cli with webpack. I think there was a good reason, but cannot remember!

Thanks in advance!

---

So I just tried starting a brand new project with angular-cli and it does work, so it must be an issue with my project.

I did a quick `npm update` and, thankfully, I'm getting a response when I try `ng init`. It tells me to follow the migration guide here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.12

I'm going to do the migration, and I *think* (well, hope) that it will solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had edited angular-cli.json and had used single quotes around a filename, whereas the file format appears to require double quotes.

I suggest that you check your angular-cli.json, for either this error, or some other formatting error.

Comment: Unfortunately that was not the issue, but thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up starting the project and loading my existing code into it manually. Unfortunately I do not have a real solution for my problem.